# MySQL Connection and Data Fetch

Tags: php, mysql, database

So I've been trying to modify some code that I downloaded, and the below code is at the top of a file:

```
private $db; // Holds mysqli Variable

    function __construct(){
        $this->db = new mysqli('justcodeus.ipagemysql.com', 'autolike', '[my password]', 'autolike');
    }
```

Then further down I created a function to fetch a user's email:

```
public function get_email($username){
        $query = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
        return mysql_result($this->db->query($query),0);
    }
```

Then, finally, in another file I have:

```
if($this->model->get_email("someuser") != null){
            echo "User's email address is " . $this->model->get_email("roomzinchina");
        }else{
            echo "Could not find user or the function failed to run and/or turned up an error.";
        }
```

When run, I get the `Could not find user` message, even though in my database there is a test username of `someuser` with the email `someuser@gmail.com`. Any idea on why this might not be working?

Edit:
At the top of the third file mentioned is `require("model.php");` and `$this->model = new Model();`. Also, if I change `return mysql_result($this->db->query($query),0);` to `return "test";` it works so it must be some issue with the database connection I think.

Comment: you are mixing mysql_* with mysqli_* decide what you want to use..

Comment: @DeiForm Could you explain where I am mixing the two please?

Comment: `new mysqli` establishes a mysqli connection. `mysql_result` uses the mysql extension. They don't work together.

Comment: Here: `return mysql_result($this->db->query($query),0);` I think `$this->db->query()` makes mysqli query. I do not know which framework are you using so cant tell you much more but try this `mysqli_data_seek($result , int $offset)`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by DeiForm, I was confusing `mysql_*` with `mysqli_*` which meant that I could not use `mysql_result`. I fixed my function code by changing it as below:

```
public function get_email($username){
        $query = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
        $result = $this->db->query($query);
        $result->data_seek(0);
        $row = $result->fetch_row();
        return $row[0];
    }
```